# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scopedFn' of undefined". What is this?

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to use RadListView with Nativescript-Vue, and i'm trying to use a v-template header, and after it, a normal v-template with my list itself.

1) My header appears to not being recognized, and it always shows only the normal v-template on fullscreen, ignoring header.

2) When I try to put a name on my standard v-template, my app crashes and I receive the error mentioned on this question title.

Why is this happening and what does it means?

This is for a List that needs to be shown below a GridLayout (the header) with height=200. I don't know what else I could try to solve this problem.

```
<RadListView @scrolled="onHomeListScroll" for="(post, index) in list" ref="listView" row="0">

       <v-template name="header">
          <GridLayout height="200" />
       </v-template>

       <v-template name="standardTemplate">
          <Label text="test" />
       </v-template>

</RadListView>
```

Comment: You haven't closed the `GridLayout` tag, not sure it was just a typo you hit here. Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduce.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. But i resolved the problem mentioned in the question. I'll soon explain.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved setting **Grid Layout rows property** to **200**.

For some reason, **row** works, and **height** don't.